# A simple application of Hölders inequality (I think)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm reading a paper where the following inequality appears.
$$
\| \widehat{f} \|^2_{L^2(d\mu)} \leq \| f \ast \widehat{\mu} \|_p \| f \|_{p^\prime}
$$
where $f$ is a real-valued measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^{\prime}} = 1$.  I think $\| \cdot \|_p$ and $\| \cdot \|_{p^{\prime}}$ are with respect to Lebesgue measure.

$$
\widehat{\mu}(\xi) = \int e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} d\mu(x)
$$

I feel like this should be a consequence of Hölder's inequality and some identities relating convolution and the Fourier transform, but I can't figure it out.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does $\|f\|_p$ here refer to Lebesgue measure? Or $\mu$?

Comment: What is $\widehat{d\mu}$. I understand the notation when we have only $\mu$, but does $d\mu$ mean the Radon-Nikodym derivative, or what?

Comment: @Davide: a straightforward computation shows that the the usual Fourier-Stieltjes transform $\hat{\mu}$ must be meant.

Comment: @t.b. Maybe straightforward but I should have done it.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume $\mu$ finite. By Hölder's inequality,  $$\tag{*}\lVert f*\widehat\mu\rVert_p\lVert f\rVert_{p'}\geq \int_{\Bbb R^n}(f*\widehat \mu)(x)f(x)dx,$$
hence it's enough to show that the RHS of this inequality is the LHS in the OP. First, we can write 
\begin{align}
(f*\widehat \mu)(x)&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x-t)\widehat\mu(t)dt\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x-t)\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{-2\pi its}d\mu(s)dt\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n}f(x-t)e^{-2\pi its}d\mu(s)dt,
\end{align}
and putting it in (*), we have, denoting $g(x):=f(-x)$, 
\begin{align}
\lVert f*\widehat\mu\rVert_p\lVert f\rVert_{p'}&\geq \int_{(\Bbb R^n)^3}f(x-t)f(x)e^{-2\pi its}d\mu(s)dtdx\\
&=\int_{(\Bbb R^n)^3}g(t-x)f(x)e^{-2\pi its}d\mu(s)dtdx\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n}(g*f)(t)e^{-2\pi its}d\mu(s)dt\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\widehat{g*f}(s)d\mu(s)\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\widehat{g}(s)\widehat f(s)d\mu(s)\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}|\widehat f|^2d\mu(s),
\end{align}
what is wanted.

Comment: +1, but don't you need finiteness of $\mu$ in order for the Fourier-Stieltjes transform $\hat\mu$ to be defined e.g. in the second equality you write after $(\ast)$?

Comment: You are perfectly right. I worried about $\sigma$-finiteness without thinking before about well-definiteness of the Fourier transform. Thanks!